# How do I simulate new bank transactions using Yodlee DAG accounts?

Tags: yodlee

I have been trying to test a Yodlee integration using their DAG test accounts but I am uncertain if I am using them in the correct way:

Once I configure Yodlee to link to the expected catalog/account, the initial import fetches all the expected transactions held on the relevant XML file. At this point I can then upload an updated XML file to DAG. In order to simulate the addition of new transactions to a bank account in a realistic way, should I upload a new XML file containing only the new transactions, or do I need to add the new transactions to the existing XML file (retaining those original transactions that have already been imported)?

Answer (score 0):

Chris since dag's are dummy accounts what happens is when you add a new xml The new transactions will be appended. For example - Initially if you added an xml with 2 transactions and then again if you will add new xml with lets say 2 existing and 2 new transaction then there will be total 6 transaction(duplicates will not be identified for dag accounts).

So in your case you need to upload an xml with only new transactions and you will get old as well as new transactions.